# Помогите упростить запрос sql

Tags: php

Есть таблица **"import"** в базе sql со столбцами:

```
nomer
user_name
user_gruppa
user_data
user_spec
user_level
user_discipl
user_semestr
user_control
user_ocenka
user_id
id
```

Каждому пользователю в системе присвоен номер:

**nomer** = какому то числу (например 467375)

Т.е. зайдя на  определённую страницу под пользователем, из таблицы import должны отобразиться строки данных, удовлетворяющих значению столбца nomer ==  "467375"

С помощью вот этого запроса:

```
$query = 'select * FROM import WHERE import.nomer != "" ';
$result = mysql_query($query) ;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$rows[]=$row;
}
```

Я начинающий программист, и сделал ужасную выборку с колоссальной нагрузкой на сервер.

И прошу помочь мне упростить этот запрос, т.к. страница на сервере выводит ошибку:

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Хотя раньше всё работало. видимо мощности урезали сервака хостер и теперь нужно заниматься оптимизацией запроса. в php я начинающий. может подскажите как упростить запрос ?

Comment: "должны отобразиться строки данных, удовлетворяющих значению столбца nomer == "467375"" ..........."С помощью вот этого запроса ....... WHERE import.nomer != "" "  --- 

Comment: А во-вторых, если в базе много данных, то стоит задуматься о постраничном выводе информации (пагинация и LIMIT в условиях)

Comment: "Я, Алёна Владимировна, сделал ужасную ошибку". И, сдаётся мне, не одну.

Comment: Всё решил. всем спасибо. А Алёна Владимировна это левый аккаунт на рабочем компе. 

Вот:

 $query = "select * FROM import WHERE nomer='{$user->profile_info[profilevalue_104]}' ";
 $result  = mysql_query($query) ;
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
           
             $rows[]=$row;
 }

Comment: И всё летает, запрос моментально находит. без проблем и нагрузок